# How to show data in TableLayout in post Method of AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, android-tablelayout

I want to show `ArrayList` of `JSON` format in `TableLayout`. 
`TableLayout` is dynamic and used in `onPost` method of `AsyncTask`.

How to get Data From `ArrayList` into `TableLayout`.
This Is my activity in which I am using the `TableLayout`.

Want to Show `ArrayList` in `TableLayout`, `ArrayList` with the name of ContactList.

```
  public class DailyMonthlyPerActivity extends Activity implements   OnClickListener {

/////...VARIABLES...//////////////////
String month,week;
Button btnShowRpt;
UserFunction userFunction;
//JSONObject json,json_user;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private static String url = "http://192.168.0.2/SOmething/Something/1" ;
TableLayout tl;
TableRow itemsName ;
TextView tvItemName0 ;
TextView tvItemName1 ;
TextView tvItemName2;


private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "Address";
private static final String TAG_DATA = "Name";
private static final String TAG_ID = "Name";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "Name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "Age";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "Name";
private static final String TAG_GENDER = "Name";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "Age";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "Name";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "Name";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "Name";
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
////////////////////////////


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily_monthly_per);

    contactList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
     itemsName = new TableRow(this);
     tvItemName0 = new TextView(this);
     tvItemName1 = new TextView(this);
     tvItemName2 = new TextView(this);
    tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutLocationSaleandRecovery);
    btnShowRpt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShowReports);
    btnShowRpt.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.getId()== R.id.btnShowReports)
    {
        new GetContacts().execute();

    }

}
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DailyMonthlyPerActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
         if (jsonStr != null) {

            try {
                JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = c.getString("Name");
                    String email = c.getString("Age");
                    String address = c.getString("Address");
                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    //contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    contact.put(TAG_CONTACTS, address);
                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }   
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        itemsName.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        tl.addView(itemsName, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        tvItemName0.setText(TAG_NAME);
        tvItemName1.setText(TAG_EMAIL);
        tvItemName2.setText(TAG_CONTACTS);
        itemsName.addView(tvItemName0);
        itemsName.addView(tvItemName1);
        itemsName.addView(tvItemName2);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: @MD this is showing Error Please Elaborate this a little bit thanks

Comment: K:  `this is showing Error`  then add log with question

Comment: @MD where to get the TAG and I am not working in Two different methods.Sending Data from DOInBackground and then Showing Data in OnPost Method... Both of the methods are of Async task

Comment: Not Giving Error But Showing Nothing in the table Layout

Comment: probably `TAG_NAME` value is visible in Table?

Comment: yeah TAG_Name is Key and I want the Value of it But it is showing the Key In Tablelayout

Comment: Using `tvItemName0.setText(TAG_NAME+":"+contactList.get(0).get(TAG_NAME)); ` first value is probably  visible . to show all values use for loop to iterate through `contactList` and add TextView to Table row

Comment: I am Getting this error................01-30 12:25:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(984): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.Now Try this.remove these lines from oncreate

```
 itemsName = new TableRow(this);
 tvItemName0 = new TextView(this);
 tvItemName1 = new TextView(this);
 tvItemName2 = new TextView(this);
```

Use this post excecute Method.I have added those lines inside this PostExcecute() Method.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                // Dismiss the progress dialog
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
itemsName = new TableRow(this);
     tvItemName0 = new TextView(this);
     tvItemName1 = new TextView(this);
     tvItemName2 = new TextView(this);
                    itemsName.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    tvItemName0.setText(contactList.get(i).get(TAG_NAME));
                    tvItemName1.setText(contactList.get(i).get(TAG_EMAIL));
                    tvItemName2.setText(contactList.get(i).get(TAG_CONTACTS));
                    itemsName.addView(tvItemName0);
                    itemsName.addView(tvItemName1);
                    itemsName.addView(tvItemName2);
                    tl.addView(itemsName, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                }
            }
```

Comment: I hope this will work for you.Any query ask me again.

Comment: again error in these lines.................................. tvItemName0 = new TextView(this);
     tvItemName1 = new TextView(this);
     tvItemName2 = new TextView(this);

Comment: Ok.Give me a minute let me check.

Comment: @MalaikaKhan Replace `this` with `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @SANJAY GUPTA one More issue.... is that THIS IS SHOWING THE SAME VALUE NOT THE value of array.. that is different

Comment: @Rehan Can you tell me Why I am getting the Last Data of the arraylist and not the full array data in TableLayout

Comment: @MalaikaKhan The code looks fine apparently. Please post your updated code for further help

Answer (score 1):

Use These lines in your postExcecute method.

```
 itemsName = new TableRow(DailyMonthlyPerActivity.this);
                tvItemName0 = new TextView(DailyMonthlyPerActivity.this);
                tvItemName1 = new TextView(DailyMonthlyPerActivity.this);
                tvItemName2 = new TextView(DailyMonthlyPerActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your postExecute() method.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                // Dismiss the progress dialog
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
                    itemsName.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    tvItemName0.setText(contactList.get(i).get(TAG_NAME));
                    tvItemName1.setText(contactList.get(i).get(TAG_EMAIL));
                    tvItemName2.setText(contactList.get(i).get(TAG_CONTACTS));
                    itemsName.addView(tvItemName0);
                    itemsName.addView(tvItemName1);
                    itemsName.addView(tvItemName2);
                    tl.addView(itemsName, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                }
            }
```

Comment: I Am getting this error.........................01-30 12:25:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(984): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: You have 2 answers on the same question, please delete one of those.